# Apache 2.4 and mod_perl 2 on Ubuntu 14.04: local configuration

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, perl, localhost

I'm trying to get Apache 2.4 configured such that I can test mod_perl 2 code locally (I should note that I have little recent experience with Apache). I've installed both of them on a machine running Ubuntu 14.04 and everything *seems* to be working (e.g., when I direct a browser to `http://localhost` I'm shown the default Apache page).

I followed the steps in [this short tutorial](http://41j.com/blog/2012/09/installing-apache2modperl-on-ubuntu-12-04/) to configure Apache such that any file in the folder `var/www/perl` (which I created) will be executed by mod_perl. I placed the specified `<Location>` directive within the `<VirtualHost>` block in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default` configuration file (perhaps I should be creating a new `VirtualHost` instead?).

Unfortunately, when I attempt to visit `http://localhost/perl/hello.pl`, I get a 404 error, so evidently some aspect of my Apache configuration isn't correct.

Given my limited knowledge of Apache, I'm probably making a simple mistake. I've found a number of contradictory pieces of advice online (some of which I suspect are simply out of date), so any suggestions would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

I was able to create a status page at `localhost/perl-status` by roughly following the first part of [this tutorial](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/635/A_brief_introduction_to_mod_perl_-_Part_1), although I had to place the new `<Location>` directives at the end of `000-default.conf` in the `sites-available` directory instead of in a new file in `/etc/apache2/conf.d` (as the `conf.d` directory no longer exists in Apache 2.4). The resulting status page indicates that mod_perl is loaded, but I've yet to get Apache to execute perl scripts. Since my initial post, I've tried a few different configurations and folder structures within `/var/www/` (including nesting the `perl` folder within `/var/www/html`) but none have worked. I'm certain this can't be particularly complicated, but finding up-to-date references is proving rather difficult.